# activate accordion by found accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In [jquery ui doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate) , there is method by index to activate accordion.
However I want to activate from "accordion found".
What must be replaced by **`???`** in code below, or any other solution

```
var accordion = $('.ui-accordion')   

accordion.each(function () {
    var hashHref = $.param.fragment(); //hashHref is the anchor href of relevant accordion
    $(this).find("a[href='#" + hashHref + "']").???;                
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791256/jquery-accordion-remember-active-area-when-clicking-back-from-an-external-link/7222736#7222736), this solves the case:

```
  accordion.each(function () {
    var hashHref = $.param.fragment();
    var findElement = $(this).find("a[href='#" + hashHref + "']");
    if (findElement.length) {
        var ndx = $(findElement).parent().index() * 0.5;
        $(this).accordion("activate", ndx);
    }
});
```